# Need to subtract hours from time stamp in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to prepare a time zone converter from India to Tanzania in an Excel sheet. I want to subtract Hours from the Time stamp. Eg : If I enter 30-Jun-16 5:30 it should convert to Tanzanian time : 30-Jun-16 3:30. Excel cell is picking hours as Time so it's giving an error when time is 2:29 or less as the difference is 2 hours 30 minuets.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "-TIMEVALUE("2:30")" to adjust the time zone difference.

Comment: Can you share your current equation in Excel that is giving you the error?

Answer (score 0):

date add function should treat you just right

```
 DDate = DateAdd("d", -3, Date)
```

OBV you need to look up syntax on your own to figure out the correct time sig, but this should put you on the right path